# Inner Join versus Union All

Tags: mysql, sql, union, inner-join

**Which version of the query is faster / best practice?** (Curiousity thing.)

<s>*More importantly, are they equivalent?*</s>

*Do these queries accomplish the same thing in this example?*

1) INNER JOIN with two OR conditions:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT (cat.id) as 'Cat ID:'
FROM
  cat
INNER JOIN cuteness_showdown ON
  (cat.id = cuteness_showdown.cat_1 OR cat.id = cuteness_showdown.cat_2);
```

2) Query each column separately and UNION ALL:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT (table_1.id) as 'Cat ID:'
FROM
  (SELECT
    cuteness_showdown.cat_1 AS id
  FROM
    cuteness_showdown
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    cuteness_showdown.cat_2 AS id
    FROM
    cuteness_showdown) AS table_1;
```

**Now, which version is faster / best practice if I need a column from another table?**

1) INNER JOIN with two OR conditions (no change):

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT (cat.id) as 'Cat ID:',
  cat.name as 'Cat Name:'
FROM
  cat
INNER JOIN cuteness_showdown ON
  (cat.id = cuteness_showdown.cat_1 OR cat.id = cuteness_showdown.cat_2);
```

2) Query each column separately and UNION ALL (needed to INNER JOIN cat table):

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT (table_1.id) as 'Cat ID:'
  cat.name as 'Cat Name:'
FROM
  (SELECT
    cuteness_showdown.cat_1 AS id
  FROM
    cuteness_showdown
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    cuteness_showdown.cat_2 AS id
  FROM
    cuteness_showdown) AS table_1
INNER JOIN cat on
  (table_1.id = cat.id);
```

Comment: Are they equivalent? No, they do two completely different things. JOINs link two tables together based on common values, UNIONs combine two (potentially unrelated) result sets into one result set.

Comment: I know that, but what I meant was, do they do they accomplish the exact same thing *in this example*?

Comment: Just a side note: bracketed columns that follow `DISTINCT` in your sample queries seem to indicate that `DISTINCT` in those cases, in your opinion, is being applied to those particular columns. It is not so: `DISTINCT` is always applied to the entire row being returned. And the column enclosed in brackets is no more than that, a column enclosed in brackets. That is, if you just like putting columns in brackets like that and it doesn't mislead you nor any of your fellow developers/DBAs, fine. Just thought I'd tell you in case you had that misconception about how `DISTINCT` functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find out which is faster, break out a terminal, write a script that runs each 1000 times and compare the results :)

As for whether they are equivalent, the query optimiser will very often come up with the exact same execution plan for several SQL queries that do the same thing, so they may well be. I can't tell you whether these ones will get that treatment, but you can use EXPLAIN to see the execution plans for yourself and compare them, assuming you have some data.

If the execution plans are indeed the same, best practice is about choosing the more readable statement so that anyone else who comes along to maintain the code can do so easily. Alternatively, if they are not the same, then you have to decide whether a harder-to read statement is worth the extra performance gain, which depends on how big a deal performance is in your project. I'd argue that if you have a relatively small DB which is unlikely to scale much and sub 10ms response times, then performance isn't an issue so just make it easy to maintain.

Comment: I think readability is subjective. I strive for consistency, and personally I use explicit `JOIN` syntax whenever possible, versus implicit, or something like the #2 example I gave. So for me, I would choose #1, all other things being equal. I will try your advice! I was just lazy I guess.

Comment: I did not try the test to figure out which is faster yet (I'll report back when I do), but this is the best answer to my question.  However, I ended up using Simon's suggestion in my query.

Answer (score 2):

There is another option,

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT (cat.id) as 'Cat ID:'
FROM
  cat
INNER JOIN cuteness_showdown ON
  cat.id IN (cuteness_showdown.cat_1,cuteness_showdown.cat_2)
```

Very minor difference, but anecdotally IN() has always seemed to execute more efficiently against keys than an OR, will see if I can mock up some tables for some firm data one way or the other.

Comment: My favorite version and the most readable in my opinion, thanks!

Comment: Also works just as well with an addition of `,cat.name as 'Cat Name:'` if desired before the "FROM"